# Failed to sync the gradle for firebase in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

I am trying to use the firebase sdk in my project in which i cannot able to sync the gradle.I have updated the jdk from 1.7 to 1.8 as well as updated the google repository,android sdk and tools to latestt version but even i am getting the error as unable to load the class 'com.google.gson.JsonObject'.

Project Gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
} allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

Module Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "nidhinkumar.firebaseexample"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

}
packagingOptions{
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'

}
 }dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.2.1'
compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.1.9'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'
 }
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Error:

```
Error:Unable to load class 'com.google.gson.JsonObject'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:<ul><li>Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
  <a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a></li><li>The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt.  Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
  <a href="stopGradleDaemons">Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)</a></li></ul>In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message you posted has the solution mentioned in it:

> Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's
>     dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network
>     connection timeout.)   Re-download dependencies
>     and sync project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle
>     build process (daemon) may be corrupt.  Stopping all Gradle daemons
>     may solve this problem.   Stop Gradle
>     build processes (requires restart)
>
> In the case of corrupt
>   Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing
>   all Java processes.

After restarting the IDE also do `File -> Invalidate Cache / Restart` because it says your cache is corrupt.

**Update from conversation in comments**

The pre-requisites should be met. As you mentioned you are using AS 1.0.1 which is less than what firebase requires - AS 1.5 and above. Upgrade your Android Studio and you should be good.

Comment: I have invalidate cache and restarted android studio

Comment: read the full answer. read the full error message. there are three solutions in the error message.

Comment: I have tried all the steps above but it doesn't works

Comment: Try removing and compile...  Then add again and compile

Comment: I have removed and compiled and it works fine but when i  added it again and compiled it shows the same error

Comment: Are you using the correct version? Cross check the version on the official site once

Comment: i am using android studio 1.0.1 whether it cause the problem bcoz in the documentation they have given android studio 1.5 or higher

Comment: well then that's it ... pre-requisites are important. upgrade - you are far behind. The latest is 2.1 and you are missing out on a lot of new features and performance improvements.